# Combining two XPaths into one

Tags: xml, xpath

I have only this XPath:

```
/queryresult/pod[position()=2]/subpod/plaintext
```

and I want to add another XPath:

```
/queryresult/pod[position()=3]/subpod/plaintext
```

What I should do?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you can combine *xpath<sub>1</sub>* and *xpath<sub>2</sub>* using the union (`|`) operator:

*xpath<sub>1</sub> `|` xpath<sub>2</sub>*

however, you might prefer to use this XPath,

```
/queryresult/pod[position()=2 or position()=3]/subpod/plaintext
```

to exploit the commonality between your two particular XPaths.